# Windows 10 PowerShell 5.1 new-filecatalog unable to find files

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to create a catalog to verify a backup created by `RoboCopy`, containing ~150GB / 100K files, using `New-FileCatalog` in Windows 10 via:

```powershell
New-FileCatalog -Path I:\Users\ -CatalogFilePath .\i_users.cat -CatalogVersion 2.0
```

- After a few hours of processing, I receive error:

  ```powershell
  New-FileCatalog: Unable to find file I:\Users...
  ```

  ```powershell
  PS $ New-FileCatalog -Path i:\Users\ -CatalogFilePath .\i_users.cat -CatalogVersion 2.0

    New-FileCatalog : Unable to find file gapi.loaded_0=I:\Users\susan\Documents\Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print & Reviews _ Temple & Webster_files\cb=gapi.loaded_0 to hash.
      At line:1 char:1
        + New-FileCatalog -Path i:\Users\ -CatalogFilePath .\i_users.cat -Catal ...
          + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-FileCatalog], InvalidOperationException
          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToFindFileToHash,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewFileCatalogCommand


  PS $ $PSVersionTable    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1023
    PSEdition                      Desktop
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1023
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


  PS $ Dir 'I:\Users\susan\Documents\Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print & Reviews _ Temple & Webster.html'
    Directory: I:\Users\susan\Documents

      Mode      LastWriteTime           Length    Name
      ----      -------------           ------    ----
      -a----    21/03/2021   8:50 PM    861394    Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print & Reviews _ Temple & Webster.html


  PS $ New-FileCatalog -Path 'I:\Users\susan\Documents\Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print & Reviews _ Temple & Webster.html' -CatalogFilePath .\i_test.cat -CatalogVersion 2.0
    Mode      LastWriteTime           Length    Name
    ----      -------------           ------    ----
    -a----    20/06/2021  12:43 PM    701       i_test.cat
  ```

Hang on if it can't find the file how does it know its name?

- The complete file path is always displayed correctly (excl. extension) and thought it might be file permissions/ownership issues, but I have no issues accessing/opening the same files from other utilities [Explorer] or from `New-FileCatalog` with just the problem file
- I have tried launching PowerShell as Administrator with no difference
- I'm unsure how to progress the `New-FileCatalog` to complete the catalog, as there doesn't seem to be an option to skip, continue, and report any files that are a problem

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the full error?  You can replace  your name if it contains a space, with something generic that has a space.  Why is your user profiles located on another disk other than the system disk?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: The user profile is a backup.  Backups are normally kept on secondary drives. The error I quoted is the full error.  I could give you one of the names of the files but there's nothing special about any of names of the failing files.  Yes some of the names have spaces in them. Most of the files have spaces in their names.  They are all shorter (much) than 250 characters.  And no other utility has an issue with them!

Comment: There must be more to “Unable to find file I:\Users....”, I also want the entire PowerShell line, to verify the code is correct.  Can you please provide the information required and necessary to answer your question?

Comment: There is more printed out but nothing related to the error.  The file are just from Documents folder.  I'll edit hthe post and add the full command.

Comment: I'm running the command again and I'll screen shot the complete error!

Comment: Are any of the "directories" actually junctions? I know they cause problems with recursive permission/ownershiip changes.

Comment: I have noticed the error message doesn't contain the file extension for the file but can make no comment as to whether this is normal or not.

Comment: And as you can see now, it has no issue with that same file if provided alone.

Comment: I seems that the folder `Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print &
Reviews _ Temple & Webster_files` is not present. Check if it exists. It should have been created when the html file `Art Illusions Sunset Pier Canvas Print & Reviews _ Temple & Webster.html` was saved. If it doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio it's not a folder it's a file.  I suppose that let's you know how broken New-FileCatalog actually is.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I used these powershell commands to do what I needed.

> Get-ChildItem -i:\Users -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-String -Width 500 | tee -FilePath I_users.txt

(I chose MD5 rather than SHA256 because it's faster)

This had no issue finding and hashing every file.

Rather than use test-catalog to perform the compare I then repeated the above command on the other volume and manually compared the txt files with a visual diff tool!  Job done!

So my opinion is the New-FileCatalog command is unreliable.